# document migration name extraction

Tags: sql

I have a scenario and would like to see if anyone has any suggestions on how I should tackle it. Basically I have a directory full of files, document names consist of `[Code]-[number]-[text]`

> CODE - A generic 3 letter code.
>   NUMBER - a number generally 4 - 5 digits in size.
>   TEXT - original document name (Before it was dumped).

CODE, NUMBER and TEXT are separated by a colon (-). Number always starts at the 5 character.

I would like to somehow scan that directory and extract the number from the filename, I would then like to compare that number to a field in a database (SQL query fairly straight forward, could also extract as raw text) If the number matches the number in the database I would like to separate those files.

If I need to clarify anything please ask. I wasn't sure if this site is appropriate for my query.

Comment: This likely belongs elsewhere, but I don't know where exactly.

Answer (score 0):

Open the root folder, click in the file explorer path (in open space off to the side so the whole path gets highlighted), type `cmd` and hit `enter` to open a command prompt from that folder location.

Type: `dir /b /s > filelist.txt`  to get a list of all file names.  You can exclude `/s` if you don't need/want to dig down into subfolders.

I'd paste that into excel, if you have 2013 you can just start typing the part you want to extract, after you type the full first line when you start typing the next line it will recognize the pattern and you can just hit `enter` to fill down.

Otherwise, use `Data > Text to Columns` and specify `-` as a delimiter.

Likewise you could just import the filelist, separate them in SQL using `SUBSTRING()` or similar.  When you have your matching filenames you can just use some concatenation to build a `COPY` or `MOVE` .bat file, pretty easy in SQL or Excel.